# probability that the lift safely reaches the ground

Tags: statistics, probability

The maximum weight that an elevator in an apartment complex can accommodate is 800kg. The average adult weight be about 70 kgs with a variance of 200. What is the probability that the lift safely reaches the ground when there are 10 adults in the lift?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow! I'm assuming you meant the variance is 20 kg, that the weights are independent of each other, and that the weights of adults are normally distributed.

The Variance of 10 adults would be = 10*20kg = 200
The Mean weight of 10 adults would be 10*70kg = 700

If the weight > 800kg causes the elevator to "unsafely" reach the ground, then we can find the upper tail of our normal distribution: P(Weight of 10 adults > 800kg).

Z-score = (X-mu)/SD(X) = (800-700)/sqrt(200) = 7.07

P(Weight of 10 adults > 800kg) < 0.000000001

Pretty much zero. That z-score shows that a combined weight of 800+ would be over 7 standard deviations above the expected group mean.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ??

Comment: which formula you used to find probability ??

Comment: We have standardized the group body weights, so we can use  a standard Normal distribution to find the probability of sampling a weight > 800kg. You can use a z-table to find the proportion of theoretical samples greater than 800 kgs or you can use the pdf of a normal distribution ($\mu$=0,$\sigma$=1), or you can use a package such as python's symbulate package: 1- symbulate.Normal(0,1).cdf(zscore)